# Get Parameter from a URL posted in a WEBVIEW in android

Tags: android, webview

1. I open the webview pointing to a website. The URL will include 2 storage variables. One is "USERNAME" and one is "PASSWORD" . The first time the webview is opened, the "email" and "password" will be empty.
2. After the user enter the data in USERNAME and PASsWORD, the URL will contain that data, 
   "I want to Extract them".

Is it possible to get these parameter from a URL in webview in android.

Need suggestion and hints to proceed in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you want it's to set a webviewclient for having onPageStarted listener which give you you url that you can parse to get parameters.

```
_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // check if you are on the right URL and parse it
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks a-ton for your useful suggetion, I have started working on it. I want work on "sniffing the urls in the webview" can you have more suggestion related to this topic. It ll be a great help for a new developer like me in android.:) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The WebView has a method [getUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29) to retrieve the URL of the current website shown in the WebView. So you should be able to extract the username and password from the string returned by that method.